# Want to know what's wrong?

Tags: trigonometry, logarithms

I take a exercise from apostol's book. I was trying the next exercise and do it, but the answer (from the book) is different, and I don't know what part of my procedure it's wrong?. So I want to know what's wrong with my procedure .

Exercise: Let $c$ be the number such that $\sinh (c) = \frac{3}{4}$. (Do not attempt to compute $c$.) In each case find all those $x$ (if any exist) satisfying the given equation. Express your answers in terms of $\log (2)$ and $\log (3)$.
$$\log (e^{x} - \sqrt{e^{2x} -1}) = c $$
solution: No real x exists.

My procedure:

Call $z=e^{x} - \sqrt{e^{2x} -1}$ then $\log (e^{x} - \sqrt{e^{2x} -1}) = c$

$$\rightarrow  \log (z) = c$$
$$\rightarrow  \sinh(\log (z)) = \sinh(c) $$
$$\rightarrow  \frac{z-\frac{1}{z}}{2} = \frac{3}{4}$$
$$\rightarrow  \frac{z^2 -1}{2z} = \frac{3}{4}$$
$$\rightarrow  z^2-1 = \frac{3z}{2}$$
$$\rightarrow  z^2-\frac{3z}{2}-1 = 0$$

then $z_{0}= -\frac{1}{2}, z_{1}= 2  \Rightarrow z=2$
then $ e^x - \sqrt{e^{2x}-1}=2 \Rightarrow (e^x-2)^2=e^{2x}-1 \Rightarrow e^{2x}-4e^x+4=e^{2x}-1 \Rightarrow 5=4e^x \Rightarrow x=\log(\frac{5}{4})$

so that's my solution, is there something wrong?

Comment: With $x=\log(5/4)$, $e^x - \sqrt{e^{2x}-1}\neq 2 $. So, when you had $e^x-2=\sqrt{\cdot}$, you can only square both sides if $e^x-2\geq 0$.

Comment: then my mistake was to assume that $e^x - \sqrt{e^{2x}-1} = 2$ .... beacuse procedure is't wrong... So I have to show there's no exist $x$ for $e^x - \sqrt{e^{2x}-1} = 2$?? And then the solution from book is correct

Comment: You picked $z=2$ correctly, as $z$ must be positive (it is the argument of a logarithm). Then you correctly concluded that you would need to find $x$ such that $e^x-\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}=2$. You can rewrite this as $e^x-2=\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}$, from which you immediately see that you need to impose $e^x-2\geq 0$ (a negative number would never be equal to a square root). Then you square both sides (all fine and correct), and find the solution $x=\log(5/4)$. At this stage, you need to verify that $e^x-2\geq 0$...and it isn't! So your 'solution' is not acceptable and must be discarded...and the book is OK

Comment: ok... thanks for your commentss ... Now I understand...